# How share template value between subchart?

Tags: charts, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i have made a chart consisting of two subcharts:

```
my-chart
├── charts
│   ├── nginxg
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── OWNERS
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   │   └── service.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   ├── mongo
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── OWNERS
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── mongo-deployment.yaml
│   │   │   ├── mongo-service.yaml
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   └── values.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

At my-chart/charts/mongo/_helpers.tpl there is define declaration

```
{{- define "mongodb.fullname" -}}
```

that has the name for the service that exposes the mongo pod and inside yaml file is referenced with:

```
{{ template "mongodb.fullname" . }}
```

@edit

I want to use this value in my-chart/charts/nginx/deployment.yml however i get an error . The error says

```
Error: render error in "nginx/templates/deployment.yaml": template: nginx/templates/deployment.yaml:11:18: executing "nginx/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.Values.service.type>: can't evaluate field type in type interface {}
```

Comment: what error are you getting. it should be doable. `Parent charts and subcharts can share templates. Any defined block in any chart is available to other charts.` Check this: https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#sharing-templates-with-subcharts

Comment: Could you provide your `nginx/templates/deployment.yaml`?